# Get TFS alerts to use friendly names rather than user names for check-in and other fields

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is there any way to get TFS to display friendly names rather than user names in TFS Alerts (notifications) ? Our company uses ID numbers as usernames, which makes the alerts next to useless until I go into TFS through Visual Studio and dig up the changesets and view the metadata on it.  Actually, even then, the history still isn't very useful because I still can't get a real name for the user until I look up their ID number in another system.

Comment: I'd say your company's doin it rong.  Good luck convincing them of that, though.

Comment: I'm interested to see if there's an easier way to do this.  Barring that, an option you would have would be to create your own web service that you set up to be triggered on WorkItem changes (etc.).  Then, you could pull together whatever information you wish, and send an email through your SMTP gateway.

Comment: We also have a Number as id instead of names.The only place we see the names is under Team members.It becomes so difficult to check the person who has checkout/checkin the files
Here is the link i found.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsadmin/thread/164a66c8-1859-409d-9ca6-7208b10ecc8f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notifications that come from TFS will always use the usernames. Sorry, it's not possible to change it to use the display names.